# How to uniquely display SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Task 9
What is the total cost of medications prescribed by each vet each day? Only display the vet’s id, date of visit and the total cost. Sort the report by the vet’s id and the date of visit.

This is the output I got:

```
VET_ID  VISIT_DATE  TOTAL_COST
V01     21-Apr-2004 36.49
V01     21-Apr-2004 38.49
V01     21-Apr-2004 41.88
V01     21-Apr-2004 40.24
V01     21-Apr-2004 35.99
V01     21-Apr-2004 35.99
V01     27-Apr-2004 32.5
V01     27-Apr-2004 37.89
V01     27-Apr-2004 32
V01     27-Apr-2004 34.5

SELECT Visit.Vet_id, Visit.Visit_Date, (Basic_Cost + Cost) AS Total_Cost
FROM Visit
INNER JOIN Medication ON Visit.Vet_id = Medication.Vet_id
ORDER BY Vet_ID, Visit_Date;
```

This is the expected output:

```
Vet Date      Total Cost
--- --------- ------------
V01 21-APR-04 12
V01 27-APR-04 16.25
V01 03-MAY-04 26.5
V01 22-JUN-04 30.39
V02 21-APR-04 38.5
V02 28-APR-04 12.5
V02 16-MAY-04 27.5
V03 28-APR-04 7.99
V03 08-MAY-04 7.99
V03 13-MAY-04 28.25
V04 03-MAY-04 10.49
V04 07-MAY-04 16.75
V04 12-MAY-04 46.05
V04 13-MAY-04 22.5
V04 17-MAY-04 32.85
V04 19-MAY-04 17.5
```

Comment: Sample data would be really helpful.

Comment: You also need to put visit_date in join

Comment: Provide some sample data from both tables

Answer (score 0):

You have to `group by Visit.Vet_id, Visit.Visit_Date` after the join to calculate the sum:

```
SELECT 
  Visit.Vet_id, 
  Visit.Visit_Date, 
  SUM(Medication.Basic_Cost + Medication.Cost) AS Total_Cost
FROM Visit INNER JOIN Medication 
ON Visit.Vet_id = Medication.Vet_id
GROUP BY Visit.Vet_id, Visit.Visit_Date
ORDER BY Visit.Vet_id, Visit.Visit_Date;
```

I guess `Basic_Cost` and `Cost` are columns in the table `Medication`, if not change to `Visit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in your own query.  Sounds like it.

```
with grouped as (
    SELECT 
            Visit.Vet_id, 
            Visit.Visit_Date, 
            (Basic_Cost + Cost) AS Total_Cost
    FROM Visit
    INNER JOIN 
        Medication ON Visit.Vet_id = Medication.Vet_id
    ORDER BY Vet_ID, Visit_Date;
)  
    select 
        Vet_id, 
        Visit_Date, 
        sum(Total_Cost) 
    from grouped
    group by 
        Vet_id,Visit_Date
```